# Understanding the Staeckel conditions for separability of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, integrable-systems

I'm trying to understand the so-called Staeckel conditions, specifically the fifth one, for separability of the Hamilton-Jacobi equations, as described in Goldstein's Classical Mechanics (3:rd edition)

The fifth condition is stated as follows. Note that $T$ below is the matrix which defines the quadratic form of the kinetic energy in the Lagrangian:

> Consider the matrix $\phi^{-1}$, with an inverse $\phi$ whose elements
>   are $$\delta_{ij}\phi^{-1}_{ij} = \frac{1}{T_{ii}} $$ (no summation on $i$)
>
> where
>   $$\left(\frac{\partial W_i}{\partial q_i}-a_i\right)=2\delta_{ik}\phi_{kj}\gamma_j$$ with $\gamma$ a
>   constant unspecified vector. If the diagonal elements of both $\phi$
>   and $\phi^{-1}$ depend only upon the associated coordinate, that is,
>   $\phi^{-1}_{ii}$ and $\phi_{ii}$ are constant or a function of $q_i$
>   only, then provided 1-4 [the first four Staeckel conditions] are true,
>   the Hamilton-Jacobi equations separate.

First of all, what are the equations supposed to mean. If the first equation is summed over $j$, it reduces to $$\phi^{-1}_{ii} = \frac{1}{T_{ii}} $$
If that's the case, why not write the equation this way? A similar remark hold for the summation over $k$ in the second equations.

Furthermore, does $\phi^{-1}_{ii}$ mean $(\phi^{-1})_{ii}$ or $1/(\phi)_{ii}$? In the former case, the condition on $\phi^{-1}$ appears to reduce to the statment that $T_{ii}$ depends only on $q_i$. Correct?

The condition on $\phi$, however, I do not understand at all. If $k$ and $j$ are summed in the second equations, there is no way to infer what the diagonal elements of $\phi$ are, so how could we check the condition on $\phi$?

Following the presentation of the Staeckel condition, Goldstein considers an example where $T_{ii}=m$, so that $\phi^{-1}_{ii}$ only depends on $q_i$ (in fact, it is constant). Based on this, he concludes that the fifth Staeckel condition is satisfied. How can he do this, when he has not checked the condition on $\phi$?